# How to fix nodeJS error: parseFileSync() is not a function

Tags: node.js

I want to check whether my .env file has environmental file APP_KEY or not. If it doesn't have APP_KEY, then I am going to create a new one and save the data in .emv fikey  This is my following code:-

```
const generateApiKey    = require('generate-api-key');
const fs                = require('fs');
const envfile           = require('envfile');
const envSourcePath     = '.env';

const IS_APP_KEY    = process.env.APP_KEY;
if(IS_APP_KEY == null || IS_APP_KEY == '')
{
    let parsedEnvFile       = envfile.parseFileSync(envSourcePath);
    parsedEnvFile.APP_KEY   = generateApiKey();
    fs.writeFileSync('./.env', envfile.stringifySync(parsedEnvFile))
}
```

However, I am keep getting an error:-
parseFileSync() is not a function

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

the method doesn't exist, it's removed with v6.0.0

> v6.0.0 2020 May 21
>
> Breaking Changes:
>  API is now only stringify and
> parse

https://github.com/bevry/envfile/blob/master/HISTORY.md#v600-2020-may-21

so either install older version, or use new methods